# How know that script execution completed .in Rhino Debugger..?

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, rhino

Is there is any way to find that the execution of javascript in Rhino debugger...Is complete or not...That means that if we make a class and i want that through this class i find that the whole script was execute or not ...is there is any function ...in rhino API...

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  a method `contextReleased(Context context)` in `org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.debug.rhino.debugger.RhinoDebuggerImpl` class in run after completion of Script..

Answer (score 0):

Do you tried "print()" mothod?

This method print to Rhino Debugger Console.

For Example

```
js> print("Start"); /* Anything. */; print("End");
```

If console printed "End", script is complete.

Comment: yeah ...it work for..console..
but i want 1step head .....is there is any way to know through any java class ...